# Role based rule for Cloud Firestore access won't work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement **this rule into Firebase Firestore** in order to access the data of the table "users" (which contains name and age of some people) *if the role of the logged in user is "admin"*. Indeed I have two tables:

- **Roles** (where **every document has the same id as the registered users**) with a field **"role"** that can be valued as **"admin"**
- **Users** contains just names and ages, and *should be accessed only by logged in admins*.

This is the rule i wrote:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   match /users/{document} {
    allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(request.auth.id)/role) == "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

In firebase console inside rule playground, by trying to do a **get** as an **authenticated user** which has the role "admin", by using the following path `/users/RaafvyRPWYuN3IyqdoBa` I get a red message saying ***"Simulated reading has been refused"***

[image: Image of the error]

*it is important to note that, inside `/users/RaafvyRPWYuN3IyqdoBa` the code is indeed the ID of one of the people that are listed in the table "users"*

Here are the pictures about my database in Firestore.

[image: Roles table]
[image: People table]

Can anyone help me to understand why the rule is not working as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `get()` in a rule, you must provide only the full path to the document to fetch.  You can't use the path to reach into a field in the document.  Once you have a document fetched, then you can reach into its fields using dot notation.

Secondly, to use the uid of an authenticated user in a rule, use `request.auth.uid` (not "id").

```
allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/roles/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "admin"
```

I suggest familiarizing yourself with the [documentation on accessing other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) for more details and examples on how this works.